# Getting emulated pmem to work on ARM v8/aarch64

Tags: linux-kernel

I am working on a PMDK application that I want to run on an ARM v8 machine, but I have a problem with the `memmap` kernel option. This option allows me to emulate PMEM in Linux over x86 architecture [1], but it does not work with my machine with kernel version `5.4.0`. I have enabled NVDIMM-related configuration in the kernel, but I don't see any updated type 12 device or even a different address mapping.

Is there any other way to emulate PMEM over the ARM v8 machine? And if not, how do others test PMDK applications over ARM v8?

[1] https://pmem.io/knowledgebase/howto/100000012-how-to-emulate-persistent-memory-using-the-linux-memmapkernel-option/

Comment: I also tried on kernel version - 5.15.0